# Is there a way to send multipart SMS message which is longer than 160 character with Qpython?

Tags: sms, multipart, sendmessage, qpython3

I'm making a SMS robot for my phone that sends delivery time for customers. And the message is over 160 characters.

I successfully sent messages with less than 160 characters with Qpython. But I have not found a way to send multipart SMS.

This is what I have used so far:

import androidhelper

androidhelper.Android().smsSend(01000000,'SMS text')